# Error al pasar objeto por FormData y POST

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

La siguiente función busca todas las preguntas y respuestas que se han generado en una tabla de manera dinámica para realizar un cuestionario de x numero de preguntas con x numero de respuestas.

Sin embargo cuando queremos pasar el objeto a un archivo php con formData mediante POST. Este imprime un arreglo vacío del lado del servidor aunque en consola nos imprime el arreglo de manera correcta.

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Preguntas</th>
      <th>Respuestas</th>
      <th>Acción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="bodyTablaEncuesta">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
function addPregunta(){
    var preguntaEncuesta=$('#preguntaEncuesta').val();
    var inputs = $("#divinputsRespuestas").find("input");
    var respuestas = "";
            var respuestasArray= new Array();
            $.each(inputs.serializeArray(), function(_, field) { 
                respuestas += field.value + "<input type='hidden' name='respuestas' value='"+field.value+"'><br>";   
                respuestasArray.push(field.value);             
            });
            pregunta.push([{'pregunta':preguntaEncuesta},{'respuestas':respuestasArray}]);
    $('#bodyTablaEncuesta').append(                     
                        '<tr>'+
                          '<th scope="row">1</th>'+
                          '<td>'+preguntaEncuesta+'<input type="hidden" name="preg" value="'+preguntaEncuesta+'"></td>'+
                          '<td>'+respuestas+'</td>'+
                          '<td><a type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="borrar(this);"><spam class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></spam></a></td>'+
                        '</tr>');
//console.log(pregunta);
}
```

```js
function agregarMuestreo(){
  var content = new Array();
  $("#bodyTablaEncuesta tr").each(function(){
    var aux = new Array();
    aux['p']=($(this).find("input[name=preg]").val());
    aux['r']= new Array();
    $(this).find("input[name=respuestas]").each(function(){
      aux['r'].push($(this).val());
    });
    content.push(aux);
  });

  console.log("final:");
  console.log(content);
  
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('us'));
  formData.append("content",content);

    $.ajax({
              dataType: 'json',
              data: formData,
              url: 'php/agregarMuestreo.php',
              type: 'POST',  
              contentType: false,               
              cache:false,
              processData: false,
              beforeSend: function(){
                $('#resultado').html('<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Ingresando, espere por favor</div>');
              },
              success:function(data){
                if (data=='1') {
                    $('#resultado').html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Los datos fueron agregados correctamente</div>');
                         $('#us')[0].reset();
                         vpb_pagination_system('1');                    
                }else { 
                  $('#resultado').html(data);  
                      }
              }
            });
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Del lado del servidor unicamente imprimimos los datos con:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Se requiere ver el **HTML donde se encuentra el formulario** y el **código PHP que maneja los datos enviados al servidor**, para responder adecuadamente a tu pregunta. Puedes colocarlo [haciendo click aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/125598/edit) para editar la pregunta. En el código compartido, **tampoco veo dónde envías el formulario al servidor**. ¿Podrías indicarlo? Se requiere el uso de Ajax para ello, como podrás comprender.

Comment: Si, ocupamos ajax para realizar el envio del formulario.

Comment: De entrada, no veo en el código HTML compartido **nada que tenga el id="us"**,  por lo que puede que estés sacrificando tu información al hacer esto: `var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('us'));`. ¿Podrías decir que es ese `us` en tu DOM? Si cambias esta línea: `data: formData,`  por esto: **`data: content,`** quizá entonces se envíe algo al servidor.